# Why can I modify a const return-by-reference?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> test;
test.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::value_type("test", "123"));
std::string& x = test.at("test");
x += "hi";
std::cout << x << ", " << test.at("test") << std::endl;
```

This code prints "123hi, 123hi", as expected.

This is counter-intuitive, because `unordered_map::at` returns a const reference:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at

So, if I make a reference to the return of `unordered_map::at`, I shouldn't be able to modify its contents, correct? Or have I completely misunderstood the meaning of const returns? The way I understand it, this code shouldn't even compile.

Now, if I change `std::string&` to `std::string`, I see the copy constructor executed as expected. The program prints `123hi, 123`, showing that the value contained in the map is not modified.

Two questions here:

1. Why can I modify a const reference?
2. If I were to use the string x to execute a move operation, such as `std::move(x)` (referring to the original declaration of `string& x`) would the move be carried out as expected, or does it ultimately turn into a copy constructor because of the const reference?

Comment: There are both a `const` and a non-`const` Version of `at()`

Comment: @AdrianW This information was already given in the correct place (i.e. the answer section), before your comment. Please avoid answering in comments.

Comment: Did you misread the note on the first overload on the page you linked to as "until C++11"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unordered_set::at` has two overloads, one for `const`-qualified and one for non-`const`-qualified instances.The one for `const`-qualified instances does indeed return a non-modifiable `const` reference. Try this:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> test = {{"test", "123"}};
// ^^ Note the const-specifier

std::string& x = test.at("test"); // No way, compiler will complain
```

This example shows that the return value of the `const` version of `std::unordered_set::at` can't even bind to a non-`const` reference, let alone that reference being modified.

Answer (score 14):

> `unordered_map::at` returns a const reference

No, it doesn't. It has two overloads: one const, one not. You are using the non-const overload.